# Can you please explain what is happening in this simple django function? formset=OrderFormSet(request.POST,instance=customer)

Tags: django

**I am a beginner to Django so I am trying to grasp the basic concepts...what happens
at the  `formset=OrderFormSet(request.POST,instance=customer)`? Does the `formset` get filled with some `request.POST` data? Does it get sent to the server? Why is there the `request.POST`?**

```
def createOrder(request, pk):
OrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Order, fields = ('product','status'), extra=10)
customer=Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
formset=OrderFormSet(queryset=Order.objects.none(),instance=customer)

if request.method=='POST':
    
    formset=OrderFormSet(request.POST,instance=customer)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return redirect('/')
context={'formset':formset}
return render(request, 'accounts/order_form2.html',context)
```

Comment: documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your "formset" variable you begin with an empty queryset so we are in a case where we will append something to a queryset. If you get a POST request, your form is submitted and will be processed. This means the customer fills in the form and submits it via POST. So your "formset" variable will be assigned the submitted data that is contained in request.POST

You will then validate the submitted data using the is_valid() method. This method validates the data introduced in the forms and returns True. If the form is valid